# SR NOR LATCH characteristic

Tags: digital-logic, switches, design

In a SR NOR latch, assume my present state for Q=0, Q'=1. Now my inputs are S=1, R=0. According to sr nor latch for that inputs I should get output/next state as Q=1,Q'=0 but I dont understand how, as Q'=1 of ps is my input along with R=0 which gives next state output as 0 but is is supposed to be 1. please help i have an exam soon. thanks!

Comment: If Q=0 and S=1 the Q' gets set to 0 as 0 nor 1 = 0. When Q' gets set to 0, Q gets set to 1 as it's 0 nor 0 = 1.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in a real circuit changing R or S to 1 will yield Q=0 and Q'=0 for one gate propagation delay time.

Comment: Hey alex, thanks for your answer. But, in the same case as you said, what if we do it the other way. If we start from Q'=1 and R=0, O NOR 1, will give output of 0, i.e. Q=0. Now Q=0, will be input with R=1, 0 NOR 1 gives 0. So Q and Q' is 0 and 0. which shouldnt happen. Please try the other way, you started from Q=0, and S=1, please start doing it from Q'=1 and R=0. PLease @Alexxx

Comment: The SR NOR latch is symmetric so it's all the same: If Q'=0 and R=1 the Q gets set to 0 as 0 nor 1 = 0. When Q gets set to 0, Q' gets set to 1 as it's 0 nor 0 = 1.

Comment: You may be talking about a condition when R and S both = 1. Obviously in this case both Q and Q' = 0 which is really an invalid condition.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not 100% sure what your question is, is it about how the gates are arranged or about the logic..

But what I have interpreted is the following:

Present state is stated as Q=0 Q'=1 from the truth table below this indicates that the SR is RESET.

Now S=1 and R=0 (stated) so this puts the Latch into SET state, giving Q=1 and Q'=0. So everything checks.

" I dont understand how, as Q'=1 of ps is my input along with R=0 which gives next state output as 0 but is is supposed to be 1."

Q' is not a input in the normal sense, it is in the question to explain what the current state is so the next state can be determined.

**EDIT**

From the gate level perspective Q=0, Q'=1 the feedback is keeping it in this state. Then S=1, R=0; it is all in the timing of the events. When S gets pulsed to a 1 Q' flips to 0. This cascades to the other gate flipping it Q to a 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/RS_Flip-flop_(NOR).svg/200px-RS_Flip-flop_(NOR).svg.png

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, assume '+' as NOR. but suppose your present state is Q=0, Q'=1. You can get output Q=1, Q'=0 by setting it in 1 way: Q'=1 + R=0 gives output Q=0 which is not correct according to the table above. This Q or the output of Q'=1 + R=0 is your input in second NOR gate like in sequential circuits and with S=1+Q=0, Q'=0, which is correct for Q' but not in case of Q.

Answer (score -1):

nice question.I figured out what your problem is all about and why are you stuck there.Solution :

As you said we started with 
                 ------------------>>>>>>>>            Q=0 and Q'=1

Now see the structure of NOR latch.
Q' is connected to input of NOR gate alongside R as feedback.

Q  is connected to input of NOR gate alongside S as feedback.

Now according to feedback loop 
------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>> 1st S=1 and feedback from previous Q=0  comes and NOR gate gives the output Q'=0

This Q'=0 is fed as feedback to input of NOR gate along with R
Now feedback =0 and R=0.
------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>> Thus Q=1

Finally we have 
-------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>  Q=1 and Q'=0 when S=1 and R=0

So all you have to do is think about it step by step and not take both feedbacks at once. Otherwise you will be stuck with the problem and obviously Q can't be equal to Q'

Comment: As you said we started with ------------------>>>>>>>> Q=0 and Q'=1

Now see the structure of NOR latch. Q' is connected to input of NOR gate alongside R as feedback.

Q is connected to input of NOR gate alongside S as feedback.

Now according to feedback loop ------>>>>>>> 1st R=0 and feedback from previous Q'=1 comes and NOR gate gives the output Q=0.

This Q=0 is fed as feedback to input of NOR gate along with S Now feedback =0 and S=1. ------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>> Thus Q'=0

Finally we have -------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>> Q=1 and Q'=0 when S=1 and R=0

Comment: Please see the above as  I changed your logic to make you understand the question. I didnt take both feedback at once. Just read this above, sorry for editing you stuff, but you may get it if you read your own with my logic.

Comment: Now according to your edits , you are selecting an output and 1 input simultaneously and deliberately trying to make the latch unstable. Lets us assume so.                                   Now Q'=1 and R=0.Now R=0 and input alongside R is 1. 0 NOR 1 will give 0. Thus Q=0 and Q'=1 .You have written wrong that ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>Now Q=0, will be input with R=1, 0 NOR 1 gives 0. So Q and Q' is 0 and 0. <<<<<<<<<<" Q=0 will be input with S and not R////////////// Check the circuit of NAND and NOR SR.  ---------------->>>>> IN NOR S <-> Q' ******************while in NAND S <-> Q

Comment: @ashley If the answer is correct, vote it as correct answer....